# Using JavaScript regex to strip substring that contains parentheses

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string called myString that contains some part the end that I do not want:

```
var myString = 'The sentence is good up to here foo (bar1 bar2)';
var toBeRemoved = 'foo (bar1 bar2)';
```

How can I use best JavaScript regex to remove the part I don't want.  The method replace() seems to have a problem with the parentheses.

Edit:

I did try to escape ( and ) like Matthew said.  I thought that didn't work, but now just tried again and it did.

```
var myString = 'The sentence is good up to here foo (bar1 bar2)';
var toBeRemoved = 'foo (bar1 bar2)';
document.write(myString .replace(/foo \(bar1 bar2\)/i, ''));
```

Thanks Matthew.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the parens as `\(` and `\)`.  E.g.

```
myString.replace(/\w+\s+\(.*?\)/, "")
```

Comment: I thought I did that but that didn't work, but I just tried again and it did.

Comment: cathat, maybe you were using the `RegExp` constructor.  In that case you need to double escape parens (and other characters).